# Table design for Holiday with alternate working day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a table design for Holiday list. if any illegal holiday comes (say All India bundh) we need to give altenate working day. how to design the table for alternate working day?

```
SELECT [HolidayID]
  ,[HolidayName]
  ,[HolidayDate]
   ,[LocationID]
FROM [Holiday]
```

Comment: What is the `IsActive` does in your table shouldn't that day be a working day if it isn't active?

Comment: How does it combine with predefined holiday lists? If any unexpected holiday comes why you want to handle it in your predefined hoiday list table?

Comment: application is designed like that. if any unexpected holiday comes, i need to enter the date and my application works - Isactive will do nothing here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get 100% what you want to do here but from my speculation, here an idea (correct me when I am wrong)

If your application allows any table modification, add an extra column for a flag, say TempHoliday. If it is an unexpected holiday, enter the holiday like any other day but turn on the temp flag. At the year's end, you can remove all the holidays with TempHoliday value of 1. 0 will be your regular holidays.

Again, I am only speculating and I am not sure how much changes your application will allow you to do.